# Can I modify a freepik and then sell it?

Tags: copyright, illustration

I don't get it... if I buy the rights from drawing X in freepik why I cant simply do whatever I want, like putting another colour and arrow on top and sell it to somene else?

Comment: what does the license agreement say?

Comment: And then someone takes the image you worked on, add a little circle somewhere and sell it on as their own. And they (rather than you or the original creator) get paid for doing ten seconds of work on something others have spent hours working to create. Does that sound like a fair deal to you?

Answer (score 9):

## Disappointing that you didn't read the easy to see disclaimer...

On every single picture you can click where it says: (Free for commercial use with attribution / How to attribute?) and in plain english will explain to you.

Source: https://www.freepik.com

---

You must credit the image to its author:

In order to use a psd or a part of it, you must credit the author, so we can continue to create new graphic resources every day.

How can I credit the author?

For websites:
Please, copy this code on your website to accredit the author:

You are free to use this image:

- For both personal and commercial projects and to modify it.
- In a website or presentation template or application or as part of your design

You are not allowed to:

- **Sublicense, sell or rent any of FreePik Contents (or a modified version of FreePik Content).**
- Distribute FreePik Contents unless it has been expressly authorized by FreePik.
- Include FreePik Contents in an online or offline database or file.
- Offering FreePik designs (or FreePik --Contents modified versions) for download.
- To use any of Freepik's images as the only or main theme of your designs.
- Acquire the copyright of FreePik Contents.

---

## Specifically about Premium license.

Where you can use Freepik resources:

- Websites
- Software, apps, games
- Printed and digital media (magazines, newspapers, books, cards, labels, CD, DVD, films, television, video, e-mail)
- Advertisement and promotional items
- Presentation of products and public events
- Multimedia
- Decoration (either private or public)

What you CAN do:

- You have the non-exclusive, non-transferable, non-sub licensable right to use the licensed material an unlimited number of times in any and all media for the professional or personal uses listed above.
- You may alter and create derivative works.
- Your rights to the Licensed Material apply worldwide.

What you CAN'T do:

- **Sublicense, sell or rent any Freepik content (or a modified version of Freepik Content).**
- Distribute FreePik Content unless it has been expressly authorized by Freepik.
- Include Freepik Content in an online or offline database or file.
- Offer Freepik designs for download.
- Use any of Freepik's images as the main theme or the only theme of your designs.
- Acquire the copyright of any Freepik content.

Source: https://support.freepik.com/hc/en-us/articles/202728521-What-am-I-allowed-to-do-with-my-premium-subscription-licenses-

Comment: bit it **does** say that Sublicensing is forbidden. OP may modify the content but may not resell that content

Comment: @BlueWizard I went ahead and marked that in bold. I also added the premium license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where you live and use that image. In developed countries there are copyright laws which say that the copyright owner declares the restrictions of usage and how much you must pay.

It's common that different licenses cost different sums of money and you cannot buy the right to resell the image as your own creation or as the major part of your own creation. Freepik at least states just this very clearly in their license. So, they do not allow adding an arrow, recoloring and selling the result as your own work.

Of course, it's possible that they allow you to sell it as their product, if you negotiate well and pay enough.

Often you cannot legally include a purchased image even as a minor part of your own work without clearly writing visible the name of the copyright owner. That detail sometimes can be removed if you purchase higher price license.

If you happen not to find any license declarations, that do not make them non-existent. It's your job in that case to find that no restrictions exist. Before doing it you cannot be sure can you use the image legally.

In many countries no agreement can change the original creator of an existing image - it's written in the law. But one can sell the right to resell the usage licenses and collect royalties.

Read the license, accept the limitations and pay what is asked or do not use the image. There's no other legal option except if you happen to be in a place where the copyright laws are not valid and you are not a citizen of a country where those copyright laws are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to learn this is to ask a lawyer on your own country but it's not a good intention and it may cause serious issues in your future life.

Learning to make it by your own is safe, legal, comforting and probably easier way. Dealing with laws, regulations, people who want to take their rights can make you to fall into depression. It is definitely not worth it.

Learn and do your own work.

Comment: This is generally good advice. But this particular license agreement is pretty black and white.